# NavigationEvents onWillFocus vs useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native

new to React Native and just playing around with it.

I don't seem to follow the differences between either using NavigationEvents with onWillFocus vs useEffect?

The scenario I playing around with coming to an account screen where it will display user details it has fetched via axio to an external api.

I been playing around with both but in all honestly don't fully grasp the differences just yet.

Any one able to shed light for me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`onWillFocus` fetch data every time when you navigate to this screen,
`useEffect` will fetch just when a component mounting or updating